# J-Query Console Error

Tags: jquery

I am having some issue with the code below.  Console tells me that line 27  is not working..not sure why.  This code is supposed to be a simple fizzbuzz if statement that for some reason is not working correctly.  Could you advise?

```
$(document).ready(function() 


function get_Value (i){ 
                       if (i % 3 === 0 & i % 5 ===0)
                      {
                          return "FizzBuzz";
                      }
                       else if (i % 3 === 0)
                      {
                          return "Fizz";
                      }
                      else if (i % 5 === 0)
                      {
                          return "Buzz";
                      }  
                      else
                      {
                        return i;
                      }
            }   
}
 $('#getNumber').click(function() {
    var numInput = $('#numInput').val();
    var value = get_Value(numInput);
    $('.Buzz ul').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    numInput.val('').focus();

 });



  });
```

Comment: also change this `if (i % 3 === 0 & i % 5 ===0)` to `if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 ===0)`

Comment: isn't $(document).ready() redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors. Here's your correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    // brace missing here

    function get_Value(i) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {  // && logical operator
            return "FizzBuzz";
        } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            return "Fizz";
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            return "Buzz";
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
            // a brace was hanging here
    $('#getNumber').click(function () {
        var numInput = $('#numInput').val(); // val is string

        numInput = parseInt(numInput, 10); // parse in integer

        var value = get_Value(numInput);
        $('.Buzz ul').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');

        $("#numInput").val('').focus(); // the object, not its value

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

upon initialization `numInput` variable is not an input text. it is rather the `val()`.
you should do this at line 27.

```
$('#numInput').val('').focus();
```